# How run custom actions for list on subsite

Tags: modal-dialog, custom-actions

I made new solution for custom actions run by on custom ribon.

Code from eventreciver:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
    string webRoot_URL = web.Url;
    SPSite site = new SPSite(webRoot_URL);

    using (SPWeb webRoot = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(SYG_AcceptOnList_faktury.Properties.Resources.s_lista);
        if (list != null)
        {
            var actionUnlockPayment = list.UserCustomActions.Add();
            actionUnlockPayment.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView";
            actionUnlockPayment.Rights = SPBasePermissions.ManageLists
                | SPBasePermissions.CancelCheckout | SPBasePermissions.AddListItems
                | SPBasePermissions.EditListItems | SPBasePermissions.DeleteListItems
                | SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems | SPBasePermissions.ApproveItems
                | SPBasePermissions.OpenItems | SPBasePermissions.ViewVersions
                | SPBasePermissions.DeleteVersions | SPBasePermissions.CreateAlerts
                | SPBasePermissions.ViewFormPages | SPBasePermissions.ManagePermissions
                | SPBasePermissions.ViewUsageData | SPBasePermissions.ManageWeb
                | SPBasePermissions.AddAndCustomizePages | SPBasePermissions.ApplyThemeAndBorder
                | SPBasePermissions.ApplyStyleSheets | SPBasePermissions.BrowseDirectories
                | SPBasePermissions.CreateSSCSite | SPBasePermissions.ViewPages
                | SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions | SPBasePermissions.BrowseUserInfo
                | SPBasePermissions.ManageAlerts | SPBasePermissions.UseRemoteAPIs
                | SPBasePermissions.UseClientIntegration | SPBasePermissions.Open
                | SPBasePermissions.EditMyUserInfo | SPBasePermissions.CreateGroups
                | SPBasePermissions.ManagePersonalViews | SPBasePermissions.AddDelPrivateWebParts
                | SPBasePermissions.UpdatePersonalWebParts;
            actionUnlockPayment.Sequence = 21;
            actionUnlockPayment.Title = "Akceptuj dokumenty";
            actionUnlockPayment.CommandUIExtension = @"<CommandUIExtension><CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location=""Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.Controls._children"">
            <Button Id=""{245CAE99-A250-4E2F-8448-A108ABE688A3}"" Sequence=""100"" TemplateAlias=""o1""
             Image16by16=""_layouts/15/SYG_AcceptOnList_faktury/Images/ikonka_akceptuj_16px.png""
             Image32by32=""_layouts/15/SYG_AcceptOnList_faktury/Images/ikonka_akceptuj_32px.png""
            Command=""{A139C8C3-3475-4DAE-92AB-57C49C542D6C}"" CommandType=""General"" LabelText=""Akceptuj dokumenty"" />
            </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
            <CommandUIHandler Command =""{A139C8C3-3475-4DAE-92AB-57C49C542D6C}"" 
             EnabledScript=""javascript:function isEnabled(){var selectedCourses = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();return(selectedCourses.length >= 1);} isEnabled();""                    
             CommandAction=""javascript:AccceptFunctions();"" />
            </CommandUIHandlers></CommandUIExtension>";
            actionUnlockPayment.Update();

            var scriptlink = site.UserCustomActions.Add();
            scriptlink.Location = "ScriptLink";
            scriptlink.ScriptSrc = "/_layouts/15/SYG_AcceptOnList_faktury/js.js";
            scriptlink.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

In js.js:

```
function AccceptFunctions() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var clistUrl = ctx.$w_0;
    var ItemIds = "";
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList())
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        ItemIds += selectedItems[i].id + ",";
    }

    var pageUrl = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('/SYG_AcceptOnList_faktury/AccceptPage.aspx?ids=' + ItemIds + '&listid=' + listId + '&listurl=' + clistUrl);
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.width = 450;
    options.height = 150;
    options.url = pageUrl;
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, OnDialogClose);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

And finally in AcceptPage:

```
protected void Button_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Button_OK.Enabled = false;
        Button_Canel.Enabled = false;
        LogIMG.Visible = true;
        LogText.Visible = true;
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList oList = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(Properties.Resources.s_lista);
                if (ItemIDs.Count > 0)
                {
                     foreach (int item in ItemIDs)
                     {
                         SPListItem ListItem = oList.GetItemById(item);
                         if (ListItem != null)
                         {
                             tytuly += ListItem.Title + ", ";
                             ListItem[Properties.Resources.s_pole] = Properties.Resources.s_wartosc.ToString();
                             ListItem.Update();
                         }
                     }
                }
                oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception eA)
    {
        LogIMG.ImageUrl = "Images/icons8-Bug-48.png";
        LogText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#d82929");
        LogText.Text = eA.ToString();
    }
    tytuly = tytuly.Substring(0, (tytuly.Length - 2));
    LogIMG.ImageUrl = "Images/icons8-Approval-48.png";
    LogText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#006600");
    LogText.Text = "Zaakceptowano: " + tytuly + ".";
    Button_Canel.Text = "Zamknij";
    Button_Canel.Enabled = true;
}
```

Ok, my problem. Its work greate on root web. But dont work on subsite, that code look for list on root web.
I dont know what edit or use to force code to work on sub site.
Maybe the ModalDialog is run on root? Maybe i need sand name/url my list on subsite by javascript to dialog?